# From multiple matricies, calculate percentage of a value from each matrix and store them into a new vector

Tags: r, function, matrix, percentage, na

I searched through stackoverflow and have failed to find a solution to my specific problem. Here, I want to calculate the percentage of an element from multiple matrices with NA values, and store the calculations into a new vector - specifically, each matrix contains 1s, 0s, and NA values. This is what I have so far:

```
a<-A[!is.na(as.vector(A))] # A, B, C, D are matrices with NA values
b<-B[!is.na(as.vector(B))]
c<-C[!is.na(as.vector(C))]
d<-D[!is.na(as.vector(D))]
mm<-function(x){length(x[names(x)==1)/length(x)]} # make percentage function
Item.1<-lapply(data.frame(a,b,c,d), mm) # apply function to matrices
```

In theory, I vectorize each matrices, remove NA values, before applying the function that calculates percentages from each vector and store them into a new vector. In this case, I want to calculate the percentage of 1s in each matrix. But this is my output:

```
$a
[1] 0

$b
[1] 0

$c
[1] 0

$d
[1] 0
```

I surmise my issue lies in the function itself, though I'm unsure what's wrong. Also, alternative solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over thinking it. Below is my new function.

```
a<-A[!is.na(as.vector(A))] # A, B, C, D are matrices with NA values
b<-B[!is.na(as.vector(B))]
c<-C[!is.na(as.vector(C))]
d<-D[!is.na(as.vector(D))]
mm<-function(x){mean(x==1)} # make percentage function
Item.1<-lapply(data.frame(a,b,c,d), mm) # apply function to matrices
```

Comment: I think that's the same as `mean(x == 1)`